# A different word for "meaninglessness"

Tags: word-choice

This is where I want to apply that word:

> "He discovered the meaninglessness of consumerism and work"

I looked in dictionaries and reverse dictionaries but for some reason I can't find a word that is easier to pronounce and shorter than *meaninglessness*.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use the word "futility".

Answer (score 13):

In your context, I think **insignificance** or **triviality** would fit well.

> "He discovered the insignificance of consumerism and work."

Answer (score 13):

What about *emptiness* or *vacuity*?

Answer (score 9):

*Unimportance* is a decent synonym.  These might work even better: *emptiness*, *hollowness*.

Then, there's always *vanity*; *vanity* is a good fit, I think, but it might throw people who are more familiar with the other very different – and probably more familiar – definition of the word:

[image]

As a footnote, the OED defines *vain* as: "Devoid of real value, worth, or significance; idle, unprofitable, useless, worthless; of no effect, force, or power; fruitless, futile, unavailing."

Comment: The refrain from the book of Ecclesiastes "vanity of vanities... all is vanity" is sometimes translated as "meaningless, meaningless... everything is meaningless." To that "he discovered the vanity of consumerism and work" certainly fits both in that sentence and in the sentiment of the Ecclesiastes, e.g. " What has a man from all the toil and striving of heart with which he toils beneath the sun? For all his days are full of sorrow, and his work is a vexation. Even in the night his heart does not rest. This also is vanity." (Ecclesiastes 2:22-23 ESV)

Comment: Also, "He who loves money will not be satisfied with money, nor he who loves wealth with his income; this also is vanity."
(Ecclesiastes 5:10 ESV)

Answer (score 6):

How about **inanity**? It fits the definition, though it is somewhat obscure and easily confused with insanity.

Answer (score 6):

On a more satirical note you could go for something like:
***farce, sham, mockery, charade***

These are shorter by virtue that they are nouns in their own right and not converted to one by adding 'ness'.

If these convey the right meaning, then I'd recommend 'mockery' for the consonance effect on both c/k and m:

> "He discovered the mockery of consumerism and work"

Answer (score 3):

How about *absurdity*? It means lack of meaningfulness.

Comment: It implies the reverse, an internal conflict, misinformation - absurd things do have a meaning, it's just a false, wrong one.

Comment: @SF internal conflict implies inconsistency. Inconsistency implies meaninglessness. I agree that it has some meta-level meaning. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absurdity

Comment: Memming: Absurd is more than that. If an office requests you submit two documents, A and B, in any order, then the order is meaningless. If it requires you submit both, but document A can be only submitted after document B, and document B will be accepted only after you submitted document A, then the order is absurd.

Comment: Nonsense also means lack of sense or meaning, e.g., in Logical Positivism, it can be said that anything but definition and tautology is "nonsense" or meaninglessness; thus theology and metaphysics are meaningless nonsense. This is of course a rather technical meaning, and likely not what is intended in the provided sentence

Answer (score 2):

Not shorter, but easier to pronounce maybe:
**[Inconsequentiality](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Inconsequentiality)**

in·con·se·quen·tial  (n-kns-kwnshl, nkn-)
adj.
1. Lacking importance.
2. Not following from premises or evidence; illogical.
n.
A triviality.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **vain**. 
 or use synonyms provided in [bing.com](http://www.bing.com/Dictionary/search?q=define%20meaningless&qpvt=define%20meaninglessness&FORM=DTPDIA)

Comment: Noun form would be *vanity* and it has somewhat other meaning.

Answer (score 1):

*Pointlessness* also comes to mind.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this and choose your best fit word..

[image: meaninglessness]

Comment: 'Forthiness'??? That's not a word in any dictionary or variant of English that I'm familiar with.

Comment: @ErikKowal: results given by google translator.

Comment: Unfortunately, Google Translate is far from infallible. Googling "forthiness" leads me to conclude that it is a pseudo-English word that has some currency in the Indian sub-continent, but is not actually English in the sense that a native speaker of English would recognise and understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Floccinaucinihilipilification or just floccipend could be an answer to that question. Meaning something that holds little value. If you're looking for a term which is a bit longer.

Answer (score 0):

Vanity is the classical word for this occasion.

> I have seen all things that are done under the sun, and behold all is
>   vanity, and vexation of spirit.  Ecclesiastes 1:14

Answer (score 0):

How about *superficiality* and *pettiness*?

> [superficiality](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/superficial): the quality or state of being superficial, i.e. presenting only an appearance without substance or significance
>
> [Petty](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pettiness) implies contemptible insignificance, inferiority and small worth.

"He discovered the *superficiality* of consumerism and work."

"He discovered the *pettiness* of consumerism and work."